# Embed external JARs in Groovy project

Tags: groovy, jar

I think I have some trouble understanding the concepts of the Groovy program structure...

I would like to write a program which has a dependency on an external JAR. I can use this JAR if I add it to Groovy's /lib folder. However I would like to create the program in such a way that others can use it including the JAR so they won't need to download it from the internet, place it somewhere, etc.

How can I include the JAR into my Groovy project?

Comment: Are you building this all by hand, or are you using a build tool such as gradle?

Comment: I'm not using any build tools, so it's done "by hand".

Comment: Please explain how are you planning to distribute your program to the others? Would you be creating a JAR of your program or are you planning to share source code? Is there any issue with using a build tool like gradle?

Comment: Our test infrastructure is strongly restricted so there is no easy way of using Gradle, i.e. I would prefer sharing the source code. Building a JAR would be possible.